# How can I change the destination folder in the media library for WFFM file uploads?

Tags: wffm

We want to change the destination folder for Webforms For Marketers file uploads. How can I do this?

I already checked out the upload and the save actions but I can't find anything related, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Form Designer, when you select your `File upload` field, you can set `Upload To` property:

[image: Sitecore WFFM File upload destination folder]

Comment: Oops, didn't check the designer.